# Express route only works after the second try

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using the express framework for a node.js backend server. I am using the express router to define the different routes.

This is my `app.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);

var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

var route = require('./route');
app.use('/api/', route);

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App running on port 3000!');
});
```

This is my router `route.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var controller = require('./controller');

router.use(function (req, res, next) {

    next();

    router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {
        controller.get(req, res, next);
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

The route itself uses a controller for the logic `controller.js`

```
exports.get = function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('Hello World');
}
```

Starting the app with `node app.js` and calling the defined route `http://localhost:3000/api/test` will result in a `Cannot GET /api/test` **on the first try**. Calling the route **a second time** however will result in the expected answer `hello world`.

**What is the reason for the first call failing? Why does it work on the second try? Any ideas are appreciated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `router.use(function (req, res, next) {` will only get executed on the first request, and when you call `next()` the route was not yet added. Afterwards you call `router.get(...)` which will add the route, so it will be available the next time.

Nevertheless thats just bad, move the `.get(...)` outside of `.use(...)` (you can also get rid of it entirely).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and worked. However how would I implement a validation. The code above is a stripped down version of the actual code and in my code `next()` is only called if the stored session corresponding to the request is correct.

Comment: "move the .get(...) outside of .use(...)"

Comment: Just to make it clear, you did not do it right - that's what Jonas means.